# Wordpresss: display all categories, but if one contains only one post, display this post instead

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am still new to WordPress (and PHP) and I am trying to finalize my very first template.
Current request is to display all given (sub)categories, but if one category only has one post, it should display the post instead with an excerpt. I think I am only missing one tiny piece to complete this...

What I have so far:

```
<?php 
     if(!empty($categories)) { ?>
               
         <!-- Display Sub-Categories and description -->
         <div class="brick_list">
            <?php                   
                 foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
                     echo '<div class="item"><h4 class="item-title">' . $category->name . '</h4><div class="item-text">' . $category->description . '</div><div class="item-link"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">Read more</a></div></div>';
                 }
             ?>
         </div>

<?php }; ?>
```

I've searched the web for a solution of the "has only one post in category" task and found this:

```
if( 1 == $category[0]->count ) { ..... }
```

But I don't know how to include (or merge) this with my existing foreach loop.
Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to insert this condition right after the foreach:   if ( $category->name != 1 ), if not 1 will display the category if 1 you can add the code to display the post.

Comment: oh yeah, and the down vote is for what exactly? I am new to a topic, provided my sample code and something I have found in additon that could be part of a solution but could not get it up and running. what's wrong with my question? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it. And at the end it doesn't look that difficult :-D
I share it here in case someone else needs it

```
<?php                   
     foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
                               
         // If there is only one post available, go directly to the post
         if($category->count == 1) {
            $all_posts = get_posts($category);
            echo '<div class="item"><h4 class="item-title">' . get_the_title($all_posts[0]->ID) . '</h4><div class="item-text">' . wp_trim_words( get_the_content($all_posts[0]->ID), 30, '...') . '"</div></div>';
         
         // otherwise display subcategories
         } else {
            echo '<div class="item"><h4 class="item-title">' . $category->name . '</h4><div class="item-text">' . wp_trim_words($category->description, 30, '...') . '</div></div>';
         }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have edit your code a bit, I ahve added a condition to check the category count before diplying the div element.

```
<?php

$categories = get_categories();

if(!empty($categories)) { ?>
               
         <!-- Display Sub-Categories and description -->
         <div class="brick_list">
            <?php                   
                 foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
                     if ( $category->count!= 1 ){
                     echo '<div class="item"><h4 class="item-title">' . $category->name . '</h4><div class="item-text">' . $category->description . '</div><div class="item-link"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">Read more</a></div></div>';
                 } else {
                     // display the post with excerpt
                     }
                 }
                         
            
             ?>
         </div>

<?php }; ?>

?>
```

Let me know if you got any issue.

Comment: Thank you Mohamed! I don't understand the change to $category->name here. count makes sense for me, but name ??

Comment: oh!!  hhh sory I meant $category->count